# sum of consecutive values

Tags: sql, teradata

I have following data in a Teradata table. My requirement is a consecutive `sum between OFFLOAD_SECONDS <5 MInutes(300seconds)` and ignore the OFFLOAD_SECONDS value where `OFFLOAD_SECONDS >=5Minutes` and do the rolling sum until we get `offload_seconds >=5 minutes`.

**My Current Data.**

```
DATE        number     Time                    OFFLOAD_SECONDS     
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:24:53     ?     
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:25:32     39     
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:32:31     419
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:32:35     4     
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:32:52     17     
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:33:00     8     
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:33:08     8     
2019/03/14     461     2019/03/14 18:45:53     765
```

**Output**

```
Date        Number   consecutive sum of OFFLOAD_SECONDS 
3/14/2019   461      39
3/14/2019   461      37
```

Comment: Is there an additional column to sort the data?

Comment: Your initial data looked like you want to reset the sum when there's a zero. Now you talk about 5 minutes like *split an hour into twelve groups*? How does this relate to the new example data?

Comment: Please edit your question and the new example data in a readable format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should give you expected output. Let me know.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a4fb/3

```
    select distinct date
      , sum(case when offload_seconds>=300 then 0 else offload_seconds end) over (partition by col_sum)  as con_sum
    from 
    (
      select date, number, time, offload_seconds
      , sum(case when offload_seconds>=300 then 1 else 0 end) over( rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as col_sum
      from tab1
    ) a
    qualify con_sum<>0
```

Alternatively, this longer version with extra select wrapping the above SQL, also works:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a4fb/13

```
 select dt, nm, con_sum 
 from (

    select distinct dt, nm
      , sum(case when offload_seconds>=300 then 0 else offload_seconds end) over (partition by col_sum)  as con_sum
    from 
    (
      select dt, nm, tm, offload_seconds
      , sum(case when offload_seconds>=300 then 1 else 0 end) over( rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as col_sum
      from tab2
    ) a
) t
where t.con_sum <>0;
```

Comment: No it is not working as expected it is giving just 76 as sum but my output should be like this. 3/14/2019   461      39
3/14/2019   461      37

Comment: Well it is working, tried it in postgresql.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a4fb/3
Since Qualify did not work here, i omitted in the sqlfiddle example. Using it can skip the row where con_sum is zero.

Comment: @GSR: Updated the answer to remove qualify and add an extra SELECT and WHERE clause. Can you to see if you have changed any thing from the answer. Don't see how it is aggregating in your result.

Comment: @ Swapnil Pandey. It is working Postgresql but teradata it is not working we made small change in window function then it is working.Thank you very much.sum(case when cast(offload_seconds as integer)>=300 then 1 else 0 end) over( ORDER BY  date,number, time rows  unbounded preceding )

Comment: Okay, I though 'offload_seconds' was already an integer column, and order by date and number is redundant, at least as per this data set.

            Also, I would appreciate if you can up-vote my answer if it helped you find your solution.